# I have trouble redirecting all traffic not coming from tripadvisor to another website (WordPress)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I try to redirect all traffic that is not coming from tripadvisor to another website using php session and javascript on a wordpress website

I need help to correct my script

here is the non working script I developed using php session:

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }
    if (!isset($_SESSION['referrer'])) {
        $_SESSION['referrer'] = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : 'n/a';
    }

    $referer = isset($_SESSION['referrer']) ? $_SESSION['referrer'] : null;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var str = "<?php echo $referer ?>";
    var oktogo = str.includes("tripadvisor");
    if (oktogo== false) {
        window.location.href = ‘https://www.mySecondWebsite.com’;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry my script is not working

Comment: change `if (oktogo== false)` to `if (oktogo)`

Comment: also if you want to check false values, shorthand is `!oktogo`, or if you really wanna use the operator please use the triple equal signs, read more here: https://bytearcher.com/articles/equality-comparison-operator-javascript/

Comment: Those ‘curly’ quotes in the JS part are a syntax error. And why are you even doing this in JavaScript to begin with, why is this not all handled in PHP?

Comment: I tried this too

<code>
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
 
session_start();
 
}
 
if (!isset($_SESSION['referrer'])) {
 
$_SESSION['referrer'] = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : 'n/a';
 
}
 
$referer = isset($_SESSION['referrer']) ? $_SESSION['referrer'] : null;
 
if(substr_count($referer,"tripadvisor")){
 
header("Location: https://www.mySecondWebsite.com");
 
}

</code>

Answer (score 1):

Hello guys I've corrected the script myself thanks for your help
Here is the script for people having the same needs

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
session_start();
}

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],"tripadvisor") == 1){

$_SESSION['is_refered_from_tripadvisor'] = true;

}

if(!isset($_SESSION['is_refered_from_tripadvisor']) || $_SESSION['is_refered_from_tripadvisor'] == false){
header("Location: https://www.mySecondWebsite.com");
}
```

Comment: @Mandy B. click the checkmark next to your answer to mark it as the correct answer.